# php page atomicity and consistency?

Tags: php, session, atomic, consistency

Here is a possible scenario: A php page accesses some session variables for session with SSID 1000. On another tab, the user logs out,which means destroying the current session. I'll assume that the worst case scenario will happen: the code is still running at page 1. What happens in that situation? Does the code at page 1  still uses session vars from SSID 1000, which doesn't exist now?  Can I use "try catch" block to handle potential exception raised ? What happens to the session vars for session with SSID 1000, which I might be using for DB querying at page 1?

I know this question might be weird, but this scenario is important to me because I want to handle exception( if this situation raises an exception) and to prevent inconsistent values being inserted to DB.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are stateless. They are not in a "logged in" or "logged out" state. If the session is closed while I'm viewing a page, attempts to continue to use the session will fail. The $_SESSION will be recreated when I try to access another page - a new session. All you need to do as a web programmer is handle $_SESSION being empty.

Comment: Handling the session being empty is the same as if the user has never accessed the website and has no session.